# Any workaround to this Firefox bug? SVGElement.getScreenCTM incorrect when parent element has a transform

Tags: javascript, svg, dom, firefox

The Firefox bug in question is https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610093

It's a long-standing issue whereby the `getScreenCTM` method of an SVG element returns incorrect values when a parent above the root SVG element has a transform applied.

The following snippet should show the black circle directly under the mouse pointer inside the red box. This works correctly in webkit/blink where the css `transform` on the parent is properly calculated. In Firefox this bug causes the black circle to be offset by the same values as the css `transform` on the parent `div` element.

I've avoided the issue up until now by ensuring there are no transforms further up the dom tree, but I'm now developing this as a component where I won't have control over the parent dom.

Does anyone know an easy workaround for getting a correct transform matrix?

```js
const svgEl = document.querySelector(`svg#test-1`);
const circleEl = document.querySelector(`svg#test-1 circle`);

const handleMouseMove = (e) => {

  // transform screen to SVG coordinate space
  const mousePoint = svgEl.createSVGPoint();
  mousePoint.x = e.clientX;
  mousePoint.y = e.clientY;

  const mouseCoordsInCanvasSpace = mousePoint.matrixTransform(svgEl.getScreenCTM().inverse())
  // set circle to coords, should be mouse center in SVG coord space 
  circleEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', mouseCoordsInCanvasSpace.x);
  circleEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', mouseCoordsInCanvasSpace.y);
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
```

```css
body{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
svg {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div style="transform: translate(50px, 50px);">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" id="test-1"> 
      <circle r="10" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am confused - the bug you have linked is marked as fixed as of Ff 68. Shouldn't that be [bug 1610093](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610093)? - your test case is also using `getScreenCTM()`, not `getCTM()`.

Comment: Correct on both counts, @ccprog - thanks for pointing out my error. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

That is an annoying bug! My suggestion is to use an `<object>` element. The source/data for the object should be the SVG.

In the following example I'm using a data URL as a data source for the `<object>`, so that we at least can see something here on ST. But I imagine that the SVG should be dynamic somehow. So, to make this work you will need to load the SVG as a source of a file (`data="/file.svg"`). If you do that you have access to the `contentDocument` property on `<object>` and in that way you have direct access to the DOM of the SVG from the "outside". It needs to run from a web server and on the same domain as well.

```css
body{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

object {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="transform: translate(50px, 50px);">
  <object width="100" height="100" type="image/svg+xml" data="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"></object>
</div>
```

Here is the SVG I use in the `<object>`:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
    var circleEl;
    
    const handleMouseMove = e => {
      const mousePoint = new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);  
      const mouseCoordsInCanvasSpace = mousePoint.matrixTransform(e.target.getScreenCTM().inverse());
      circleEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', mouseCoordsInCanvasSpace.x);
      circleEl.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', mouseCoordsInCanvasSpace.y);
    };

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
      circleEl = document.getElementById('c1');
      document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    });
    ]]>
  </script>
  <circle id="c1" r="10" />
</svg>
```